# how to make pycharm debugger work with ironpython?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, ironpython

I have been using pycharm for quite a while now , 
ever since last release I can't get the debugger to
workwith IronPython i tried it with python 2.7 and 
3.4 and it works fine  I keep getting this  :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.5\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 2411, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.5\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1762, in run
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.5\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1698, in prepareToRun
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.5\helpers\pydev\pydevd_tracing.py", line 78, in SetTrace
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.5\helpers\pydev\pydevd_tracing.py", line 67, in _InternalSetTrace
SystemError: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Process finished with exit code 1'
```

I tried debugging it but I don't have a lot of experience with python 
can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same after upgrading Ironpython to version 2.7.6.3. 
I have downgraded to previous stable release 2.7.5, which has resolved the issue.